# Making RAID on a working system

Tags: raid

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop and I have two SSD disks and two 1TB Sata HDDs. I want to make RAID to SSDs each other and 1TB HDDs each other.
I searched a lot and tried many things, but I think I didn't successfully made it.

*Is there a easy way to doing this and how can I check if the operation succeed or not?*

I can't try these [instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID), because I've already installed Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahmetertem.  I did this yesterday using the package "mdadm":

1. `sudo apt-get install mdadm`
2. partition your intended drives (I let it default to ext4 for filesystem, and I used the package "gparted" for this, for your reference)
3. carefully note the device names of the drives you want to use (mine happened to be /dev/sda and /dev/sdc)
4. In Terminal:  `sudo mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level-1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda /dev/sdc` (Of course, you will use your own device names.)
   It said something like "device /dev/md0 created" and the drives went nuts creating metadata, I assume.
5. format it:  `sudo mkfs -text4 /dev/md0` (don't know if this is necessary, but it was when I first created RAID in 14.04.)
6. mount it:  `sudo mount -text4 /dev/md0 /media/raid` (that's where I wanted to put it)

My "proper answer" to your question ends here.

Aftermath and notes:
After rebooting, I wanted to mount the raid but discovered it was already mounted.  (Wouldn't do that in 14.04 without tweaking the /etc/fstab file).  I couldn't find the raid in /media/raid, but instead discovered that it was already mounted -- but where?  I found it in /media/me ("me" is my home folder name) as 023023-2341324-1234324-234134243 or something like that.

I tried to rename it, but the device was busy.  So, I unmounted it and then that long-name folder was gone.  Rebooted again.  It's back, and that long name is the same, so I tried changing the permissions and created a static link to it called "raid".  Still can't write to it, though, because of permissions/ownership troubles.

I'm sure I'll work it out in about a day.  I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Thanks for reply. --level-1 is giving error `mdadm: unrecognized option '--level-1'`

Comment: Sorry, should be "--level=1"